# Flutter app not run with android studio can anyone help me out?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app and when I try to run it, I see an error. I mention belove but app is running when I use Xcode.

In android studio:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
```

CocoaPods' output:

```
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
```

Error output from CocoaPods:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin20/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
        WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
        Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:
        export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Comment: You are launching to a iPhone 11 real phone from android studio and it fails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this error come because cocoapod new version not suport utf-8 and flutter widgets use that so you have to export following lines to your terminal and its work

> Export this line and its work

`export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code in your bash profile if you're using bash.

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

The bash profile is might be

```
~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc
```

Also if you're using zsh then the profile name will be.

```
~/.zshrc
```

Comment: still not working do you have any other solutions?

Comment: For me adding export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 and secondly adding export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 in the ~/.bash_profile file worked

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines in your shell profile file. (~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc)

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```